# magento 2 Get attribute option label by attribute option Id?

Tags: magento2, attributes, eav-attributes

magento 2 I would like to get an `attribute option label` by attribute option id.

**For Example:-**

**attribute option value :** 53,

**attribute option label/text/name :** green

from the above scenario i want to get attribute option label/text/name.

Note: without loading product i need to get this.
please suggest me.

Comment: Where do you want to get this attribute?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add following in your **__construct** method

```
protected $optionFactory;

protected $_attributeOptionCollection;

public function __construct(
  \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionInterfaceFactory $optionFactory,
  \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection $attributeOptionCollection
){
    $this->optionFactory = $optionFactory;
    $this->_attributeOptionCollection = $attributeOptionCollection;
}
```

Now you can get option data using option value;

```
$optionValue = 53; // your attribute value
$optionFactory = $this->optionFactory->create();
$optionFactory->load($optionValue); // load by option value
$attributeId = $optionFactory->getAttributeId(); // atribute id of given option value
$optionData = $this->_attributeOptionCollection
                ->setPositionOrder('asc')
                ->setAttributeFilter($attributeId)
                ->setIdFilter($optionValue)
                ->setStoreFilter()
                ->load(); // load option data by attribute id and given option value
echo "<pre>"; print_r($optionData->getData()); exit;
```

Comment: thanks for replay, but i my code i have only attribute option value. i am not able to get attribute code also. so i need attribute details by attribute option value.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: @ChanderShekhar, can we just check if optionId exist or not ? suppose i have id 53, it has to return true, else should return false.

Comment: The pointed me in the right direction.  Although use of `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\Collection` caused issue for me when multiple option ids are queried.  Should use factory method  `\Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Option\CollectionFactory`, and use `create()` but not `load()`

Answer (score 9):

Try the following code:

```
$_optionId = '53';
$_attributeId = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color');
if ($_attributeId->usesSource()) {
      $_optionText = $_attributeId->getSource()->getOptionText($_optionId);
}
```

Comment: please suggest me without loading/using product. also i have updated my questioin. Thanks for replay

Comment: ok, for that you need to create a custom module, try to follow the tutorial in this link http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-attribute-id-name-value-from-attribute-code/

Comment: in given block also they are using attribute code. but i don't have attribute code also. i want to get by attribute option value

Comment: to be honest I don't really understand why would you do it without attribute code, every attribute option is assigned to certain attribute

Comment: in my code i have only attribute option value/id With that i want toget label name.

Comment: do you have the option ID from Database?

Comment: i am getting option id but it's not from DB

Answer (score 5):

Try the below code:

```
$option_id = 5431;
$attribute_code = 'coffee_type';
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');

    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
    $optionlabel =  $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($option_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code to get option label by option Id directly from the database.

```
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$tableName = $resource->getTableName('eav_attribute_option_value');

$option_id = 350;
$sql = "select * FROM " . $tableName . " where option_id=".$option_id;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

echo $option_label = $result[0]['value'];
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: not best practice imo

Comment: In most cases if you have to use an SQL query you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: @shivashankar m  Did you find a proper way to get the data for attribute option by id without specifying attribute code? I am also in need to that!